# Font Family Similar to Unitext

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

I really like the Unitext font by Monotype, but I'm trying to avoid web fonts with page view restrictions and counters.

Can anyone suggest an alternative, paid or otherwise, that might fit the bill.

[image]

Comment: There are at least 5 similar typefaces I can name off the top of my head (would have to check web font licenses). Can you narrow things down a bit by explaining the *specific* aspects of Unitext you are trying to come close to?

Comment: I really like how compact it is, the sharp angles it uses, and I'm not sure of the right term, but just the overall crispness the lines have.

Comment: Did you ever get any alternatives as I am stuck in the same position as yourself? Thanks :)

Comment: @GudIdeas, No I never did, but it has become available with Adobe CC and the new unlimited use options. Just makes me a bit nervous using it with companies when no telling if it will disappear one day.